# Ruby app push to Heroku failed because of SQLite using Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, heroku, cygwin

I am running a Windows 7 installation.

This is the first time I have encontered a problem. After I use the command:

```
git push heroku master
```

This is the Cygwin bash output:

```
> The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.156)' can't be
> established. RSA key fingerprint is
> 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad. Are you sure you want
> to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added
> 'heroku.com,50.19.85.156' (RSA) to the list of known   hosts. Counting
> objects: 60, done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (47/47), done. Writing objects: 100%
> (60/60), 85.66 KiB, done. Total 60 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
> 
> -----> Ruby app detected
> -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
> -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
> -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
>        New app detected loading default bundler cache
>        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -  -binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
>        Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
>        Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
>        Using rake (10.1.0)
>        Installing abstract (1.0.0)
>        Installing activesupport (3.0.1)
>        Installing builder (2.1.2)
>        Installing i18n (0.4.2)
>        Installing activemodel (3.0.1)
>        Installing erubis (2.6.6)
>        Installing rack (1.2.8)
>        Installing rack-mount (0.6.14)
>        Installing rack-test (0.5.7)
>        Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
>        Installing actionpack (3.0.1)
>        Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
>        Using polyglot (0.3.3)
>        Using treetop (1.4.15)
>        Installing mail (2.2.20)
>        Installing actionmailer (3.0.1)
>        Installing arel (1.0.1)
>        Installing activerecord (3.0.1)
>        Installing activeresource (3.0.1)
>        Using bundler (1.3.2)
>        Installing thor (0.14.6)
>        Installing railties (3.0.1)
>        Installing rails (3.0.1)
>        Installing sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)
>        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native ex  tension.
>        /tmp/build_2ad04c34-9506-4a88-a27c-47f7374f0b0c/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/rub
> y extconf.rb
>        checking for fdatasync() in -lrt... yes
>        checking for sqlite3.h... no
>        *** extconf.rb failed ***
>        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You   may
>        need configuration options.
>        Provided configuration options:
>        --with-opt-dir
>        --without-opt-dir
>        --with-opt-include
>        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>        --with-opt-lib
>        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>        --with-make-prog
>        --without-make-prog
>        --srcdir=.
>        --curdir
>        --ruby=/tmp/build_2ad04c34-9506-4a88-a27c-47f7374f0b0c/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/
> bin/ruby
>        --with-sqlite3-dir
>        --without-sqlite3-dir
>        --with-sqlite3-include
>        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>        --with-sqlite3-lib
>        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
>        --with-rtlib
>        --without-rtlib
>        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2ad04c34-9506-4a88-a27c-47f 
> 7374f0b0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5 for
> inspection.
>        Results logged to /tmp/build_2ad04c34-9506-4a88-a27c-47f7374f0b0c/vendor/ 
> bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/ext/sqlite3_api/gem_make.out
>        An error occurred while installing sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5), and Bundler cann  ot
>        continue.
>        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3-ruby -v '1.2.5'` succeeds before bund  ling.
>        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
>        Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
>        Using rake (10.1.0)
>        Installing abstract (1.0.0)
>        Installing activesupport (3.0.1)
>        Installing builder (2.1.2)
>        Installing i18n (0.4.2)
>        Installing activemodel (3.0.1)
>        Installing erubis (2.6.6)
>        Installing rack (1.2.8)
>        Installing rack-mount (0.6.14)
>        Installing rack-test (0.5.7)
>        Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
>        Installing actionpack (3.0.1)
>        Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
>        Using polyglot (0.3.3)
>        Using treetop (1.4.15)
>        Installing mail (2.2.20)
>        Installing actionmailer (3.0.1)
>        Installing arel (1.0.1)
>        Installing activerecord (3.0.1)
>        Installing activeresource (3.0.1)
>        Using bundler (1.3.2)
>        Installing thor (0.14.6)
>        Installing railties (3.0.1)
>        Installing rails (3.0.1)
>        Installing sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)
>        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native ex  tension.
> 
>        /tmp/build_2ad04c34-9506-4a88-a27c-47f7374f0b0c/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/rub
> y extconf.rb
>        checking for fdatasync() in -lrt... yes
>        checking for sqlite3.h... no
>        *** extconf.rb failed ***
>        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You   may
>        need configuration options.
> 
>        Provided configuration options:
>        --with-opt-dir
>        --without-opt-dir
>        --with-opt-include
>        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>        --with-opt-lib
>        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>        --with-make-prog
>        --without-make-prog
>        --srcdir=.
>        --curdir
>        --ruby=/tmp/build_2ad04c34-9506-4a88-a27c-47f7374f0b0c/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/
> bin/ruby
>        --with-sqlite3-dir
>        --without-sqlite3-dir
>        --with-sqlite3-include
>        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>        --with-sqlite3-lib
>        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
>        --with-rtlib
>        --without-rtlib
> 
> 
>        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2ad04c34-9506-4a88-a27c-47f 
> 7374f0b0c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5 for
> inspection.
>        Results logged to /tmp/build_2ad04c34-9506-4a88-a27c-47f7374f0b0c/vendor/ 
> bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5/ext/sqlite3_api/gem_make.out
>        An error occurred while installing sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5), and Bundler cann  ot
>        continue.
>        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3-ruby -v '1.2.5'` succeeds before bund  ling.  !  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.  !
> 
>  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
> 
> To git@heroku.com:limitless-fortress-4709.git  ! [remote rejected]
> master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
> some refs to 'git@heroku.com:limitless-fortress-4709.git'
```

I am really sorry for the extensive post, I just want to make sure I can give anyone willing to help the necessary information. I know the problem it's in the SQLite gem, I just can't put my finger on it.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SQLite with heroku, you should change your production database to postgreSQL.

Check out the explanation and instructions on how to set up PostgreSQL here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: Setting up postgreSQL is kind of a PITA on windows, so you could have SQLite as your development database and postgreSQL as your production database, but it is better if they are the same. It is probably worth the effort to get postgres set up on your pc, that is what I did.

Comment: I really am I newbie so I don't have any knowlege to refute your statement, but, In the Ruby on Rails official tutorial the tutor shows its first app (a blank app with no database wich I am also, by fully following this tutorial, trying to push to Heroku) beeing pushed to Heroku while having a SQLite Gem with the same version as I do (1.2.8). Maybe its a previous version of Heroku wich allows SQLite, but I really doubt that Heroku would stop featuring SQLite databases. Thank you for your answer please do reply!

Comment: Here is what heroku says themselves:  *Your application needs to be configured to use the Postgres database. Newly generated Rails 4 applications are configured to use sqlite. To use Postgres instead add the pg gem to your Gemfile:
`gem 'pg'`
We recommend using the same database in development and production to maintain dev/prod parity. You will need to remove the sqlite gem from your gemfile or place it in a non production group. You can read more about why you should not run sqlite on Heroku, which also contains detailed instructions on setting up Postgres locally.*

Comment: I suppose you are right. Therefore, since I'm using Cygwin as my shell, is there a way to install PostGres in Cygwin rather than in my Windows 7 computer? Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't use Cygwin. That would probably be best as a separate question, but of course do research on your own first to see if the answer has already been posted.

Comment: I am just now installing PostGres on Cygwin. How do I install and make Ruby On Rails run with PG? Sorry for such inconvinience

Comment: I am having trouble now Installing the PG gem. I will open a new question for this. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I could finally push my app to Heroku :) I managed to sucssessfully install PostGreSQL on Cygwin and then, by following the instructions on the link you provided on your first reply, I created a Ruby app running on PostGreSQL and pushed it to Heroku. Thank you very much, I had no idea that Heroku had this requirement. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the issue:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Where the `rails_12factor` is another very useful Heroku production-required gem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where I am supposed input this lines?

Comment: In the `Gemfile` file in the root directory. You will find a `gem 'sqlite3'` call. Change that with this piece of code and then run `bundle install --without production`

Comment: This was no good, I did as you told me and I got pretty much the same output as I pushed to Heroku:

'  Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.
'
I'm starting to believe Heroku really can't fuction with SQLite. Or maybe its a problem in my Cygwin with the Make fuction? I'm clueless

Comment: When you setup the Gemfile like this you are telling Heroku not to use sqlite3 for production, but just postgreSQL (via the `pg` gem). Try this: remove the Gemfile.lock file, run `bundle install --without production`, commit all the changes and then push to Heroku.